# Limit of a function at $0$ using Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I'm trying to improve my skill in calculus ! We consider a function defined as

$g(x)=\begin{cases}
                \frac{x+2-(4-x^2)^{1/2}}{x}\quad x\neq 0 \\
                1\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\;\; x=0 
                \end{cases}$

And we want to find the limit of $g$ when $x$ goes to zero. What I wanted to do is to use a Taylor-lagrange expansion with $a=0$ and $b=x$ of $f(x)=(4-x^2)^{1/2}$, that is $f(0)=2$, $f'(x)=-x(4-x^2)^{-1/2}$ and $f''(x)=x^2(4-x^2)^{-3/2}-(4-x^2)^{-1/2}$ which gives $f(x)=2+\frac{\left[(\theta x)^2(4-(\theta x)^2)^{-3/2}-(4-(\theta x)^{2})^{-1/2}\right]x^2}{2}$ with $0<\theta<1$. Then we have that

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+2-(4-x^2)^{1/2}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+2-2-\frac{\left[(\theta x)^2(4-(\theta x)^2)^{-3/2}-(4-(\theta x)^{2})^{-1/2}\right]x^2}{2}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}(1-\frac{\left[(\theta x)^2(4-(\theta x)^2)^{-3/2}-(4-(\theta x)^{2})^{-1/2}\right]x}{2})=1$

Is this seems correct to you ? I can justify the fact to take $a=0$ because the domain of $g$ is $[-2,2]$ which includes $0$

Thank you a lot !

Comment: It's correct. But you only need a Taylor expansion to the first order:
$$f(x) = 2 - \theta x^2 (4 - \theta^2 x^2)^{-1/2}$$

Comment: You are totally right ! Thank you a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.